# How to store a returned javascript value in a django form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want  to store things like `Browser type` and `GPS locations` for mobile devices along with user input data.

I know how to set up a form in Django so that the user inputs are stored in the database. But how would I go about executing a Javascript function that will a return a value to be stored in the same model as all the user inputtext in the form?

Answer (score 0):

I found reasonable two ways:

1. I would go for api and do request to server with information you want to store and put it to your model (for instance REST django-rest-framework). But its more complicated since you need to handle authorisation.
2. As altenative to api you could create hidden fields in form which would be filled by js code executed from the browser. When user clicks submit button he sends you data with no need to manually provide it.